# Attribute default value: attribute.defaultValue

Tags: javascript, html

Can you get an attribute default value so you don't have to repeat it in the following example:

```
<p title="foo" id="p">Hello, world!</p>
<input type="text" id="i">
<script>
    var p = document.getElementById('p'),
        i = document.getElementById('i');
    i.oninput = function () {
        p.title = this.value;
        if (this.value == 'bar') {
            p.title = 'foo';
        }
    };
</script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jU5Tv/)**

For text field elemets there's a property known as `defaultValue`: `element.defaultValue`.
Is there something like `attribute.defaultValue`? In other words, is there something like `p.title = p.title.defaultValue` for the above example?

Comment: There is nothing like `defaultValue` you have to give it statically.

Comment: Care to rephrase the question into something more descriptive (preferably a question)?

Comment: @EmilLundberg: I tried to do it!

Comment: @Manwal: Now the question is wouldn't it have been a useful feature to add to JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jU5Tv/5/)**

If you build a nice reusable function like:

```
function el(id){
    var e = document.getElementById(id), a = e.attributes; e.default = {};
    for(var k in a)if(typeof a[k]==='object') e.default[a[k].nodeName] =  a[k].nodeValue
    return e;
}
```

not only it'll allow you to easily reference a desired element by ID like:

```
var p = el('p'),
    i = el('i');
```

but also to retrieve at any point **any** default element attribute like:

```
p.default.title // "foo"
```

or in your example:

```
i.oninput = function () {
    p.title = this.value;
    if (this.value == 'bar') {
        p.title = p.default.title ;
    }
};
```

or shortened like http://jsfiddle.net/jU5Tv/6/ :

```
i.oninput = function () {
    p.title = this.value==="bar" ?  p.default.title : this.value;
};
```

so double pleasure in any way :)
What the function does is: returns a DOM HTMLElement, but at the same time loops any Element's assigned `attribute` and stores it inside a self-assigned Object called `default`.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a default value property for input title attributes.

However, so that you're not repeating yourself you can store this in a variable before updating it:

```
var p = document.getElementById('p'),
    i = document.getElementById('i');

var defaultTitle = p.title;

i.oninput = function () {
    p.title = (this.value == 'bar') ? defaultTitle : this.value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a data attribute to hold your default title.

```
<p title="foo" data-default-title="foo" id="p">Hello, world!</p>
<input type="text" id="i">
```

In the JS:

```
if (this.value == 'bar') {
    p.title = p.dataset.defaultTitle;
}
```